# Java code to sign-in at Azure AD but need code without login to portal.azure.com

Tags: java, azure, azure-active-directory

I have use below link to access all user of Azure AD but it require user to login in portal.azure.com

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapp-java

I have also use below link to authenticate user but token return by it is not useful for access other API of Azure AD. Using above url code it allow to access other API of Azure but require portal.azure.com login.

https://samlman.wordpress.com/2015/06/04/getting-an-azure-access-token-for-a-web-application-entirely-in-code/

Need java code which doesnt require us to login in portal.azure.com for accessing it API

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Azure AD implements four flows in the [OAuth 2.0 authorization framework](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749).

And if you don't want to interact with Azure manually when acquiring the access token, you can choose the **Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant** or **Client Credentials Grant** flow based on your scenario.

And normally, we need to sufficient permission to operate corresponding resource. Please share the exact resource/request you were developing and the detailed error message to help troubleshoot this issue if you still have the problem.

And [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios) is helpful to learn about the authentication scenarios for Azure AD.